# Mapping function in LISP

Tags: recursion, mapping, lisp

I need your help on something. I have a list in input:

```
(1 ((2 3) (4 ((5) (6)))) ((7 8) (9 10)) 11)
```

I want to receive in output the following:

```
((1 2 3 7 8 11)

 (1 2 3 9 10 11)

 (1 4 5 7 8 11)

 (1 4 5 9 10 11)

 (1 4 6 7 8 11)

 (1 4 6 9 10 11))
```

The functions such as mapcar, mapcan, maplist... do not help. I think that it is necessary to use recursive function, but do not have any idea how.

Comment: So you have an input example and an output example? What the relationship between them? What did you try so far?

Comment: i am writing a program to realize some algorithm of logical inference. For the operations AND and OR I have the following denotation:

(and A B) => (A B)

(or A B)   => ((A) (B))

In output I want to receive all cases contained in the input list. For example:

(and A (or B C)) => (or (and A B) (and A C)) 

In another way:

(A ((B) (C)))       => ((A B) (A C))

Hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: @glrain Why don't you ask about that, then? It doesn't seem like a trade secret worth billions, nor is it embarassing in any way.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Of course it's not. But I think it will be hard to explain all the algorithm and how data is presented. 
My programm is almost completed, except the last function to deduce all cases that can happen. 
I tried to make the question more understandable and clear using the example above. But I must have been wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you described seems to be DNF calculation. Here is my solution:

```
(defun dnf (f)
  (when f
    (if (consp f)
        (let ((f-car-dnf (dnf (car f)))
              (f-cdr-dnf (dnf (cdr f))))
          (if (or (null f-cdr-dnf) (every #'consp f))
              (append f-car-dnf f-cdr-dnf)
              (mapcan
                (lambda (f-cdr-cj)
                        (mapcar (lambda (f-car-cj) (append f-car-cj f-cdr-cj))
                                f-car-dnf))
                f-cdr-dnf)))
        `((,f)))))
```

Is it an intern task?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it looks simple and works perfectly. I uploaded my version because I have thought about it for a long time, and I want to finish it. I just can not throw it away

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for the question. But I don't understand why function "parse" returns NIL as the result.

```
(defun parse (input &optional (res nil) (curlist nil))
  (let ((head (car input))
        (tail (cdr input)))
    (if (numberp head)
      (progn
        (push head curlist)
        (if (null tail)
          (push curlist res)
          (parse tail res curlist))
        (pop curlist))
      (if (numberp (car head))
        (progn
          (push (car head) curlist)
          (setf tail (append (cdr head) tail))
          (if (null tail)
            (push curlist res)
            (parse tail res curlist))
          (pop curlist))
        (loop for element in head do
          (parse (cons element tail) res curlist))
      )
    )
  )
  (if (null curlist) res)
)
```

Comment: If we use `res` as a global variable, then it will be ok. But it will not be a re-entrant function at all